# Deploying SSIS instance on local db

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

1. Is it possible to deploy ssis package on a localdb sqlserver instance?
2. Why don't  see 'Integration services catalog' folder in default server instance?

[image: screenshot of the sql sver instances]

Comment: Localdb AFAIK is express edition. Express editions doesn't support SSIS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841478/can-i-use-ssdt-bids-ssis-using-sql-server-2012-express

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you running locally?

Comment: the server had an express edition!That was the last thing I was going to check. Thanks a Prabhat and Tab.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible, as long as you are running an edition of SQL Server that supports SSIS, and as long as you have the SSIS Service turned on.